# Crud Generator with Laravel

Tags: laravel, crud-admin-generator

Since 2 weeks I work in a projet of devlopment of a application. I must creat many CRUD and it may take many times. Now I want to know if I can use a free crud generator laravel.If yes, which generator?
Need your Help please.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/appzcoder/crud-generator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command:

```
php artisan make:model User -mrc
```

## RESTful Resource controller

A **RESTful resource controller** sets up some default routes for you and even names them.

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Gives you these named routes:

```
Verb          Path                        Action  Route Name
GET           /users                      index   users.index
GET           /users/create               create  users.create
POST          /users                      store   users.store
GET           /users/{user}               show    users.show
GET           /users/{user}/edit          edit    users.edit
PUT|PATCH     /users/{user}               update  users.update
DELETE        /users/{user}               destroy users.destroy
```

And you would set up your controller something like this (actions = methods)

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {}

    public function show($id) {}

    public function store() {}

}
```

You can also choose what actions are included or excluded like this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', [
    'only' => ['index', 'show']
]);

Route::resource('monkeys', 'MonkeysController', [
    'except' => ['edit', 'create']
]);
```

[RESTful Resource Controller documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

## Implicit controller

An **Implicit controller** is more flexible. You get routed to your controller methods based on the HTTP request type and name. However, you don't have route names defined for you and it will catch all subfolders for the same route.

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

Would lead you to set up the controller with a sort of RESTful naming scheme:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        // GET request to index
    }

    public function getShow($id)
    {
        // get request to 'users/show/{id}'
    }

    public function postStore()
    {
        // POST request to 'users/store'
    }

}
```

[Implicit Controller documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers)

It is good practice to use what you need, as per your preference. I personally don't like the **Implicit controllers**, because they can be messy, don't provide names and can be confusing when using `php artisan routes`. I typically use **RESTful Resource controllers** in combination with explicit routes.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel already provides **CRUD** operation see: [laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers)

> Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code. For example, you may wish to create a controller that handles all HTTP requests for "photos" stored by your application. Using the make:controller Artisan command, we can quickly create such a controller:

```sh
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

**[EDIT 1]**

Or you can choose for example: [Laravel-Backpack/CRUD](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD) which comes with an Admin panel and others things like that.

**[EDIT 2]**

Also you can refer this Laravel blog to choose a generator:

https://laravel-news.com/13-laravel-admin-panel-generators

**[EDIT 3]**

Again on Laravel Blog you can see that Laravel is constantly evolving a new Artisan command have been added see:

[laravel-news.com/laravel-resources-artisan-command](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-resources-artisan-command)